# How to cope with "rejected" on git push?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a master and a beta branch. There is a situation where push is rejected:

*edit2:* I am on branch master.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 9, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 669.81 KiB, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:foobar/codedemo.git
   a5fc71d..64430c1  master -> master
 ! [rejected]        beta -> beta (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:foobar/codedemo.git'
```

Normally I would checkout beta, then pull beta and this wold probably solve it.

But because this is a production website I cannot checkout beta here. Is there a way I can pull beta without checking it out?

As this is a production site I am somehow stuck.

*Edit:* The code is also checked out on another location, can I do something from the other location to solve the problem here? There are no problems at the other location.

*Edit3:* With help of the accepted solution I could do it after some time, but I'd prefer a solution without a second client

Comment: Please specify what branch you are trying to push.  [master or beta]

Comment: @gahooa: I am on branch master

Comment: You can do pull without checking out: it is called `git fetch`. But this wouldn't help you, as you need to be able to checkout branch to resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: You *Are* aware that your master branch is successfully pushed in the example you show ?

Comment: @krosenvold: yes, but there is obviously some stuff inbeta that i cannot push before I pulled from beta. but I was looking for a smart way to pull / merge from beta without changing the checked out branch (because this is a production site where i cannot checkout beta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could push beta as some other branch, then go somewhere where you *can* check it out to resolve it.

```
git push origin beta:beta-temp
# on a different machine
git fetch
git checkout beta-temp
git rebase origin/beta # puts your new commits on top of the upstream
git push origin beta-temp:beta
git push origin :beta-temp # to delete it
```

Comment: thank you, this helped me to solve it. This means there is no simple way to (in this case) merge from origin/beta to the local beta without checking out beta?

Comment: Correct, because there's always a possibility the merge will fail, so you need to do the merge in the working tree so that you can fix the failures and commit the hybrid.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't done anything weird, then the reason for this is that the remote has a commit that you are not aware of, and allowing the push to continue would ignore that commit entirely.

Try [pulling](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) first, which will attempt to automatically merge the two commits, after which you will be able to push.

If you pull a branch that isn't currently checked out, I *think* it will still create a merge for you.

Answer (score 0):

What branch are you trying to push?

By default, `git push` will push all of your configured tracked branches.

Try this to push just the current branch:

`git push origin HEAD`